# Как проверить, можно ли удалить не более одного элемента из списка, чтобы он был строго возрастающим?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Решаю задачу: дан список, надо проверить, можно ли удалить не более одного элемента из него, чтобы он был строго возрастающим?
Как я решил: чувствую, что есть какой-то алгоритм однократного прохождения по списку в цикле, но не понимаю, как его реализовать. В итоге я в цикле удаляю по одному элементу и новый список без этого элемента просто проверяю, возрастает ли он. Ожидаемо, сложность возрастает на одну степень, решение не проходит все тесты.

Как сделать оптимальнее?

Comment: что такое `отного`?

Comment: Ну все то не нужно проверять удалением, нужно идти по массиву пока соблюдается упорядочивание, а когда оно ломается проверять, что либо последний элемент надо удалять, либо предыдущий, и не более того. Причём, если вы уже один элемент "удалили", то дальше права на ошибку уже нет и если опять сломается последовательность, то всё, можно прерывать проверку. Ну там ещё потом как-то оптимизировать, чтобы два раза не ходить за проверкой после текущего и предыдущего элементов, а ходить один раз только.

Comment: Флаг = false. Идёшь по списку да сравниваешь текущий и предыдущий. Больше предыдущего - дальше. Меньше - если флаг = true, то exit, иначе флаг = true  и сравниваешь предыдущее со следующим, больше - exit, иначе идёшь дальше. Дошёл до конца - возможно.

Answer (score 0):

счетчик = 0

Проверять, что каждый последующий элемент строго больше предыдущего. Если условие не выполняется, то счетчик += 1 и проверить, что текущий элемент так же больше пред-предыдущего. Если в конце счетчик 0 или 1, то задача выполнима. Если 2, то можно сразу все заканчивать, потому что задача невыполнима.

Comment: 3,1,2 - в конце счётчик = 1.

Comment: Так я делал, разумеется) 
Не работает для [1,2,3,5,3]

Comment: @Akina Ну и отлично, в чем проблема?

Comment: @AybulatAbdullin Почему не работает? Счетчик будет 1, убрать последнюю 3 и список станет строго возрастающим

Comment: А если 1,2,3,5,3,4 ?

Comment: @Harry ну тада надо добавить еще одну проверку

Comment: Хорошо. 2,3,1,2.

Comment: @Akina получится 2, задача невыполнима.

Comment: @Эникейщик так не получится же 2, потому что у нас только один раз не выполнилось условие, что последующий больше предыдущего.

Comment: @Akina я там дополнил ответ

Comment: *и проверить, что текущий элемент так же больше пред-предыдущего* Именно это мы проверяли на предыдущем шаге, только для (со стороны) предыдущего элемента. Дополнительно должны сравниваться последующий и предыдущий, а не текущий и предыдущий. ТО есть тестируется вариант, если текущий элемент удалён.

Comment: @Akina Совсем не это. Проверили элементы c индексами n и n-1, если n НЕ БОЛЬШЕ, чем n-1, то сравнить его еще с n-2.

Comment: Вот именно! Сперва текущий и следующий, потом предыдущий и следующий. В ответе же фраза "каждый последующий элемент строго больше предыдущего" - по всем нормам русского языка речь идёт о двух соседних элементах, термины "последующий" и "предыдущий" в данном случае означают местоположение друг относительно друга в этой паре, тем более что слова "текущий" или аналогичного во фразе нет. PS. Впрочем, автор походу уже не сдал и утратил интерес к вопросу.